# Error while using .features.haralick fiuction from mahotas library

Tags: python, anaconda3

I have imported mahotas in my program and this is the error I get

```
   File "C:\Users\Hp\Documents\Python Scripts\global.py", line 34, in fd_haralick
      haralick = mahotas.features.haralick(gray).mean(axis=0)

AttributeError: module 'mahotas' has no attribute 'features'
```

So then I imported mahotas.features and then this is the error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Hp\Documents\Python Scripts\global.py", line 7, in <module>
import mahotas.features

File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mahotas\features\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from .texture import haralick

File "C:\Users\Hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mahotas\features\texture.py", line 8, in <module>
from . import _texture

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I don't know why I am getting these errors or how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate conda environment.

Answer (score 0):

Download the package from this [link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

Then install it using this command

```
pip install path to package/mahotas‑1.4.11‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```